# JavaScript If Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code below to parse JSON DATA. Is there a mod to this code that i could use before the `' as ' + entries.credits.cast[actor].character);` in case there is not a character listed? That way it could look something like actor 1 as character 1, actor 2, actor 3 as character 3

```
var acting = [];
var maxCount = 5;
var count = entries.credits.cast.length;
if(count > maxCount) count = maxCount;
for (var actor = 0; actor < count; actor++) {
    acting.push(entries.credits.cast[actor].name + ' as ' + entries.credits.cast[actor].character);
}

document.getElementById('cast').innerHTML = acting.join(', ');
```

Comment: Of course: `if (entries.credits.cast[actor].character) { ... }`

Comment: I don't really understand what you want... but if you want to parse JSON in (probably) more efficient ways, take a look at [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: I don't really see anything there that looks like JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Conditional Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
for (var actor = 0; actor < count; actor++) {
    acting.push(entries.credits.cast[actor].name + (entries.credits.cast[actor].character  ? ' as ' + entries.credits.cast[actor].character : ''));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using the ternary operator?

```
for (var actor = 0; actor < count; actor++) {
    acting.push(entries.credits.cast[actor].name + (entries.credits.cast[actor].character ? ' as ' + entries.credits.cast[actor].character : "");
}
```

Comment: Sorry - @bits should have credit for this. I was a tad too slow :)

Comment: ha ha ok, but thank you for your answer anyway... both helped